# TensorFlow queue feed order

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm wondering in what order TensorFlow queues feed data (specifically when you have a list of tensors that they're feeding from).

For example, in  a queue like this:

```
fifo_q = tf.FIFOQueue(
              capacity=10,
              dtypes=[tf.string, tf.string]
              shapes=[[], []])
```

If I enqueue these lists:

```
sess = tf.Session()

l = [str(i+1) for i in range(10)]
x = tf.constant(l)
y = tf.constant(l)

eq = fifo_q.enqueue_many([x, y])
dq1, dq2 = fifo_q.dequeue()
sess.run(eq)
```

I would expect `dq1`, `dq2` to be '1', '1' the on the first run, then '2', '2' and so on. But this isn't what's happening. Instead, when I run the following code, I get '1', '2' and then '3', '4', and so on until `dq2` reaches 10, and then the queue locks up.

```
for x in range(6):
  print('dq1:', sess.run(dq1))
  print('dq2:', sess.run(dq2))
```

Why does this happen instead of what I expect? I'm using this to match up training examples with labels, but some training examples and labels are skipped/off-set. Is a better solution just to interleave the file names in a single queue? Either way, I would like to understand this behavior.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow queues allow you to enqueue and dequeue lists (more precisely fixed-length tuples) of tensors atomically, in a single operation. The tensors `dq1` and `dq2` are the outputs of the same dequeue operation, which in this case will remove a tuple of two tensors from the queue. Each invocation of `sess.run(dq1)` or `sess.run(dq2)` corresponds to a separate invocation of the dequeue operation, *but* when you invoke `sess.run(dq1)` TensorFlow discards the other tuple element, because you didn't explicitly request it in the call to `sess.run()`.

The solution is to ensure that **both** outputs of the `dequeue()` operation are consumed in the **same** call to `sess.run()`. For example, the following change to your program should produce the result that you originally expected:

```
for x in range(6):
  dq1_val, dq2_val = sess.run([dq1, dq2])
  print('dq1:', dq1_val)
  print('dq2:', dq2_val)
```